# How to use hash '#' in the URL with @react-navigation

Tags: react-native, url, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-native-web

I am working with react native web, where @react-navigation is used for navigation. I am using `linking` so that users can navigate using the URL.

my linking configuration looks like

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: [],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Home: '',
      Profile: 'profile',
      Settings: 'settings',
      NotFound: '*',
    },
  },
};
```

The problem is I would like to pass a parameter using # in the URL. For an example, `localhost:19006/profile#address` or `localhost:19006/profile#about`
But when I try the above URL, `react-navigation` automatically removes `#address` / `#about` from the URL.

I went through https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/

I can pass the parameter like `localhost:19006/profile?sec=address` easily, But I want to use # in the URL.

Is there any way to use # in the URL?

Note I am using the following libraries

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.1",
"react-native": "0.67.3",
"react-native-web": "^0.17.7",
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to import `Linking` from the react native.

`import {Linking} from 'react-native`

and whenever you need to open a URL  with a click event you can code below.

`Linking.openURL( "Your Link");`

Might be it helpful to you.

Comment: No, I do not want a click event. I want to browse directly `localhost:19006/profile#address`, But whenever I hit enter, `#address` is removed from the URL automatically.

Comment: Did you find how ?